I want to make all these petals face outward consistently
I am following the geometry node tutorial part of the donut tutorial and I thought it would be useful for flower petals but I ran into a problem because the petals face in random directions. I used weight painting already and I put the origin on the end of the petals, I thought from here I could change the values until they all faced outwards but this does not seem to be the case. How can I make them all face outward? and stand on their ends. Perhaps while keeping the randomness a little bit? 

There may be better ways to achieve that since Blender 4.2, but a similar question has been asked here (the source geometry is a curve, not a mesh like in your case) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316456/how-to-create-a-fluffy-tail-with-geometry-nodes/317201#317201. Hopefully it can help you ? I couldn't explain the idea better than in the link.
